# Airtable API - encoding a sort URI with multiple sort fields / directions

Tags: javascript, api, airtable

Airtable API -- how do I correctly encode a sort URI component for multiple fields / directions?

For example, this sort object with three fields and directions:

```
const sort = [
  { field: "title", direction: "asc" },
  { field: "value", direction: "desc" },
  { field: "category", direction: "asc" }
];
```

In my query builder function I have this so far but it's incorrect:

```
let sortUri;

sort.forEach(sort => {
  console.log(sort.field, sort.direction);
  sortUri += `&sort%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=${encodeURIComponent(
    sort.field
  )}&sort%5B0%5D%5Bdirection%5D=${sort.direction}`;
});

sortUri;
```

Comment: I didn't understand, exactly what do you want to do??

Answer (score 0):

I contacted Airtable support and with their help, figured it out. Each sort needs an index so it's like this.

```
const sortArr = [
  { field: "title", direction: "asc" },
  { field: "value", direction: "desc" },
  { field: "category", direction: "asc" }
];
```

In my query builder function I have this so far but it's incorrect:

```
let sortUri;

sortArr.forEach((sort, i) => {
  console.log(sort.field, sort.direction);
  sortUri += `&sort%5B${i}%5D%5Bfield%5D=${encodeURIComponent(
    sort.field
  )}&sort%5B${i}%5D%5Bdirection%5D=${sort.direction}`;
});

sortUri;
```